# Best and Most Secure way to Publish settings file to app

Tags: javascript, security, methods

I am looking to publish a set of settings that will be upgraded over time. The app needs to identify that new settings are available and download them.

I am wondering what the best way to do this is, downloadable database or XML, etc and how I can secure them as best I can for a general use app, it's not for law enforcement, etc.

Looking for thoughts, methods, pointers to code (javascript ideally), etc.

Comment: What do you mean with "secure" in here? Secure from whom? a man in the middle? the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepare your settings array somewhere and encode it as JSON:

```
<?php

$settings = array(
    'foo' => 'bar'
);

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($settings);
exit;

?>
```

Your app calls setting url and receives settings array as json
obj, which you can use right away in your javascript.

```
$.ajax({
   cache: false,
   dataType: "json",
   processData: true, // if false, posted data stays untouched
   type: "GET",
   url: "http://place-where-app-finds-settings.com/settings.php",
   success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) { 
       alert(data.foo);
   }
});
```

Sample requires jQuery ...